# How to order git history in visual studio 2015?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, git-log

I have git repo with long history. For some reason this history isn't ordered by date. It really bowers me. I have trouble reviewing code and figuring out what causes some problems. I see same mess in branch history as well as in file history. I checked this window in my colleagues's VS. some of them have ordered history and some have messy history. I didn't figured out what is different between theirs instalations.

I also checked git-log documentation and didn't find configuration for log order.

Result of `git-log` command ordered by commit date as well. So it's probably something in VS causes this mess.

How can I convince VS to show history ordered by date?

Comment: Which update of VS do you have?

Comment: update 2. version 14.0.25123.00

Comment: In VS 2017 (15.6.5) is the same problem. Parallel history is not sorted properly.

Comment: VS 2017 Enterprise (15.8.7) - I have same problem, the order of the commits is not by date.